# The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. in my project

Tags: php

I am trying to modify my data in the table. And when I run the modification I get an error The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
Below is my code

The edit method

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $category = Category::findOrFail($id);

    return view('teacher.teachercategorie.edit', compact('category'));
}
```

The update method

```
public function update(Request $request, Category $category)
{
    $request->slug = SlugService::createSlug(Category::class, 'slug', $request->name);

    $category->update($request->all());
    
    return back()->with('success', 'Category create successfuly');
}
```

The web.php file route

```
Route::get('categorie/edit/{id}', 'CategoriController@edit')->name('categorie.edit');
Route::post('categorie/update/{id}', 'CategoriController@update')->name('categorie.update');
```

edit.blade.php file code

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('categorie.update', $category->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="card-body">
              @isset($category) @method('PUT') @endisset
              @csrf  
              
              <x-inputbs4
                name="name"
                type="text"
                label="Category name"
                :value="isset($category) ? $category->name : ''"
              ></x-inputbs4>
                          
              <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('categorie.index') }}" role="button">Category list</a>
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Update</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              
            </div>            
        </form>
```

Comment: So add `put` method to your `web.php`

Comment: You defined the route as `Route::post(` but you're attempting to use `@method('PUT')`. Decide which you want it to be and make them match

Comment: And why your `edit` method is actually `view` method?

Comment: Just add a new route Route::put()